# Lambdas in Salesforce Apex

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, salesforce

Does Apex support the concept of lambdas?

Ultimately, I am trying to DRY up some really repetitive code in my tests, so I'd love to be able to pass functions around, something like this (C#-esq)

```
public static TestMethod void some_test_method(){
  Arrange( ()=>
    // some setup stuff
  );
  Act( ()=>
    // test action
  );
  System.assertEquals(...);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apex doesn't have lambdas. In fact, it [doesn't even have anonymous classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31305/does-apex-have-anything-like-anonymous-inner-classes). (That would have been your next question.) You're going to have to stick with declared classes. Apex does support Java-ish interfaces and abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try R.apex(https://github.com/Click-to-Cloud/R.apex) for a functional stylish programming, although you still have to use declared classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.